# Java: Could not resolve view with name in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, tiles

I am facing this error while I am clicking on a link to display a page. I'm using Spring MVC Tiles.

Error:

**javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'contact' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'**

Below is the code.

**tiles.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC  
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"  
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">  
<tiles-definitions>  
    <definition name="base.definition"  
        template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp">  
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />  
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />  
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/menu.jsp" />  
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />  
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" />  
    </definition>  

    <definition name="contact" extends="base.definition">  
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Contact Manager" />  
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/contact.jsp" />  
    </definition>  

    <definition name="hello" extends="base.definition">  
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Hello Spring MVC" />  
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp" />  
    </definition>  

</tiles-definitions>
```

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>

      <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>  
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>  
    </context-param>  

</web-app>
```

**servlet.xml**

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialpoint" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
      <property name="viewClass" value = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
   </bean>

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">  
        <property name="definitions">  
            <list>  
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>  
            </list>  
        </property>  
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

Comment: Do you have contact.jsp  in the specified location WEB-INF/jsp/contact.jsp

Comment: yes i do have the jsp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the following in your `viewResolver` definition:

```
 <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
```

Remove it