# javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'login' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name 'login' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'] with root cause
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'login' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'

`web.xml`:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And from a controller, we are just returning login page.

like `return "login";`

I also added a jstl dependency to the `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Not sure if you have viewResolver configured. Check this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921589/java-could-not-resolve-view-with-name-in-spring-mvc

Comment: I already tried but not working. 

Thanks @Ashish